# Which download do I choose to install VirtualBox on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I want to install VirtualBox on my Linux Mint machine (so that Mint is the host), but on the [downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) page I don't see any distributions for Mint. I know Mint is Debian-based, but not sure what to do. Does VirtualBox not exist for Mint? If so, why?!? If it does exist, why don't I see anything for Mint on that downloads page?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method is to use the Package Manager built into Mint.  The icon is a 4 pointed yellow star (well, in v13 it is) in the menu.  Start up Package Manager and type VirtualBox into the search, and you will see it.  This will not necessarily install the most current version of VirtualBox, however it will install the latest stable release - which is probably all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said Linux Mint is derived from Debian and has a ubuntu edition and a debian edition based on debian test engine. You are good to download either ubuntu or debian links because mint is with debian packaging system dpkg. Downloads on websites may not specify linux mint.

To find out which release you are in, you can try this in your terminal.

```
cat /etc/*-release
```